Why did they leave the Endurance outside the time dilation zone?
When visiting Miller's planet, the crew decides for the spaceship to remain in an orbit around the black hole instead of an orbit around Miller's planet, so that the spaceship is effectively OUTSIDE the time dilated region. They discuss this plan and consciously vote in favour of this plan.
The thing I do not understand is, that orbiting Miller's planet instead would take the spaceship INTO the time dilated region and therefore avoiding not only 23 (?) years of loneliness for the crew member remaining on board, but also minimising fuel and oxygen consumption as well as the risk of e.g. the crew member turning ill and dying.
So the question is: What advantages did the plan they then executed exhibit? What was the intention and logic behind their plan?

Miller's planet is one big plot hole.

The whole movie's one big plot hole when you think about it. I mean, I love it, but basically none of it really stands up. For example, if they can just fly into space in that little landing module then why did they need to build a giant rocket to get into space the first time?

As entertaining as the movie is, the realism of the science presented is surface level only. We who have only basic understanding of orbital mechanics and general relativity must suspend our disbelief and let go of logic if we are to appreciate the story.

Taking the Endurance into the time dilated region also means getting it back out again.

Yeah, Cooper granted. He’s got a point. In essence, getting from
Miller’s planet to Mann’s would require climbing out of the deep
gravitational well of Gargantua. It would be like swimming upstream,
against the current. Which probably wouldn’t leave enough fuel for a
return trip to Earth. If the choice was between getting back a little
late and not getting back at all, he knew where he fell out.
Interstellar - Official Novelisation


I don't recall if this was mentioned, but it always seemed strange to me that there still wasn't some time dilation from orbiting the black hole.  it's not like there's a dividing line you cross and suddenly experience some dilation, especially since the dilation difference is so extreme ...

@Michael That would be minimal, and the truth is that the time dilation due to the black hole's gravity on Miller's planet would also in reality be minimal. To get extreme factors like 7 years per hour, you would need to be metres away from the black hole's event horizon. IIRC, Kip Thorne said the only way they could physically get the time dilation Christopher Nolan wanted, would be for Miller's planet to be orbiting the black hole at close to the speed of light. (But then the Endurance would have to be, too, and there wouldn't be relative time dilation between them.)
